# What's the best data structure and algorithm for my problem?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to solve the problem: I have a text file where the columns are separated by ",". The problem is that I need to be able to search by columns. Example of the data in the file:
[image]

I will parse this file by columns and place all the data in the another data structure(s). So my question is what's the best data structure to use in the case like this (and what's the best algorithm to use for searching in this data structure)? I need to count all the entries that are matching too. For example if I chose last column and typed "4" to search it should show last two strings and count 2 entries. I was thinking on something like list, but the file is pretty big and search would take too long, and I need a solution that won't depend much on the data length. I was thinking about binary search tree too, but not quite sure how to use it here.

This is kind of learning task so I don't need just a solution (like grep), because I'm trying to implement all of this on Java. I thought maybe this problem has a common solution that some experienced programmers know, or maybe I need to think of by myself. I'm not asking for the solution or the code, just a hint what data structure/algorithm is better to use in the situation like this, some key words.

Comment: Are you aware that the most trivial, linear algorithm will take less than a second to search through 10 million items? What size are you looking at?

Comment: As I said, it's a training task, so linear algorithm is not the option, I don't need just a solution, I need theoretically good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly a database.  If that's not an option, it really depends on how you're going to query it.  Generally a b-tree is good for simple things like comparisons, but you'll need a balanced tree like AVL or red/black trees.  And you'll need 1 tree per column you want to index.  Which is basically how low complexity databases do things.

Comment: Yes, database is not the option, thanks, I will look into trees more, but I can't figure out, how would I search substrings if I use them? Because the key in the tree node is calculated for the whole string, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Most commonly you index by words and search by word or word prefix only. Have you decided that you want arbitrary substring search?

Comment: Yeah, I need to search substrings, it can be the whole word or just a part of it, at least prefix option is okay for now, maybe I will figure out the rest, but I need to understand how can I do this with the binary tree

Comment: Substring searches are a lot more complicated.  I question why you can't use an existing database solution, even a simple one like SQLite.  Unless the goal is to learn how to write a db.  But depending on what you need, breaking it up by word and using a Trie might work (that's a tree data structure for storing words, frequently used by dictionary algorithms).  It can give you whole word and prefix matching, although not a good structure for mid word matches.

Comment: You would need to parse the file, an O(N) operation, and then generate an index (B-Tree) for each column in order to achieve an O(log N) lookup. If you generated a hash index you might achieve O(1) lookup. Substring searches would add a further layer of complexity.

Comment: Also, if any new rows were added you would need to update all the indexes